# Fetch Images From ICloud Will Freeze The UI

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, phasset

I'm using BSImagePicker lib for choosing multiple images in my App, when user select Images stored on ICloud **only** the UI will freeze up on the images picker controller until the images are downloaded I tried to fix it but with no results

Here is my code :

**Choosing the images and show them in slider**

```
 @IBAction func choose_images(_ sender: Any) {

        bs_presentImagePickerController(vc, animated: true,
                                        select: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
                                            // User selected an asset.
                                            // Do something with it, start upload perhaps?
        }, deselect: { (asset: PHAsset) -> Void in
            // User deselected an assets.
            // Do something, cancel upload?
        }, cancel: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in

        }, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
            // User finished with these assets

            // print(assets.count)

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                self.imagesource.removeAll()
                self.imagesdata.removeAll()
                for img in assets{

                    self.imagesource.append(ImageSource(image:  self.getUIImage(asset: img)!))
                    self.imagesdata.append(self.getUIImage(asset: img)!)
                }

                self.slider.setImageInputs(self.imagesource)
                self.slider.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
                self.slider.slideshowInterval = 2
                self.slider.zoomEnabled = true
                self.slider.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                self.slider.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.insideScrollView
                let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap))
                self.slider.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
            }
        }, completion: nil)


    }
```

**Function to return the image for chosen assets**

```
func getUIImage(asset: PHAsset) -> UIImage? {

        var img: UIImage?
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
        options.version = .original
        options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        options.isSynchronous = true
        options.progressHandler = { (progress, error, stop, info) in
            if(progress == 1.0){
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            } else {

                SVProgressHUD.showProgress(Float(progress), status: "Downloading from iCloud")

            }
        }
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.aspectFit, options: options) { (image, info) in

            img = image
        }

        return img
    }
```

Any Help will be much appreciated

Comment: Why are you synchronously accessing the remote assets on the main queue?

Comment: If i set `options.isSynchronous` to false it will return nil !

Comment: Of course because then it is async and your code is written properly to handle being async.

Comment: @rmaddy Please could explain more what should I change in my code

Comment: Where are you using self.imagesdata?

Comment: @Rox will use it in other function to upload the images

Comment: just try with commenting this line //self.imagesdata.append(self.getUIImage(asset: img)!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are synchronously accessing the remote images on the main queue. You need to perform your loop in the background.

You need to update the code in your `finish` block as follows:

```
}, finish: { (assets: [PHAsset]) -> Void in
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        self.imagesource.removeAll()
        self.imagesdata.removeAll()
        for img in assets {
            if let res = getUIImage(asset: img) {
                self.imagesource.append(ImageSource(image: res))
                self.imagesdata.append(res)
            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.slider.setImageInputs(self.imagesource)
            self.slider.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
            self.slider.slideshowInterval = 2
            self.slider.zoomEnabled = true
            self.slider.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            self.slider.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.insideScrollView
            let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.didTap))
            self.slider.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
        }
    }
```

You may also have to update the progress handler inside `getUIImage` to update the SVProgressHUD on the main queue.

Note that with the above code you should keep your `getUIImage` as-is except for the one change I just mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Just try to replace following code

```
for img in assets{

    self.imagesource.append(ImageSource(image:  self.getUIImage(asset: img)!))
    self.imagesdata.append(self.getUIImage(asset: img)!)
}
```

with this one:

```
for img in assets{
     let image = self.getUIImage(asset: img)!
     self.imagesource.append(ImageSource(image: image))
     self.imagesdata.append(image)
}
```

Comment: While this is a good change, this doesn't change the fact that all of the image loading is being done synchronously on the main queue.